# xstream , how to hide hide the filed name of a class but display the value of the field (Java)

Tags: java, xstream

I want to get output like this:

```
<MyObj>field value</MyObj>
```

The following is  java code to format a Object MyObj, I want to hide filed in xml but display the filed value.

```
public class MyObj {
    private String filed;

    public String getField() {
        return filed;
    }

    public void setField(String value) {
        this.filed = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver("UTF-8"));
        MyObj obj = new MyObj();
        obj.setField("field value");
        xstream.toXML(obj, System.out);
    }
}
```

But the output is:

```
<MyObj>
  <filed>field value</filed>
</MyObj>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not impossible. But, remember: This is not consistent with the philosophy of xstream library, which operates on beans, which usually contain more than one field.

You can use ToAttributedValueConverter.class

```
@XStreamConverter(value=ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings={"filed"})
```

Use this annotation before the class declaration.

In my opinion, better is use something else, like this:

```
<MyObj filed="field value" />
```

This form of xml can be done using annotations @XStreamAsAttribute

Example code:

```
public class MyObj {
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String filed;

    public String getField() {
        return filed;
    }

    public void setField(String value) {
        this.filed = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver("UTF-8"));
        MyObj obj = new MyObj();
        obj.setField("field value");
        xstream.toXML(obj, System.out);
    }
}
```

The advantage of this solution is that when you need in the future to add more fields than one then you will not need much to change the xml format.

It is also faster because this solution does not need a converter.